# Dynamic <title> with PHP & MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I Am trying to get a custom title on my Webpage. I want to request it from a MySQL Database. I've read about it for about an Hour now And cannot find an answer that I had an use/sample of. 
This is the header:

```
?php
include('./includes/db_connect.php');
 $sql_title = "SELECT title FROM posts WHERE post_id='$id'";
$query_title = $db->query($sql_title); 
$row = $query_title->fetch_object();
$postTitle = $query_title;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="./includes/db_connect.php">
<title> <?php echo $postTitle ?></title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="style-top.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

$DB:

```
<?php
$db =mysqli_connect('localhost','xx','pass','xx') or die('error with connection');
?>
```

This brings an error that looks something like this:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli result could not be converted into a string on *path/path/...*

Comment: err what is `"<link href="./includes/db_connect.php">"`?

Comment: Try to spend another hour reading on SQL injections

Comment: What tutorial you were reading?

Comment: Wooooo, Take it easy bro, Seeing a beginner doesn't mean you have to -1 everything you see

Comment: What tutorial you were reading for an hour?

Comment: I googled "dynamic page titles with PHP & MySQL" and read like the first 2 pages but I didn't find any info that'd help me fix the script.

Comment: Do you understand that it is not "dynamic page titles" you need but "how to get data from mysql database using PHP mysqli"? Or, rather, "Basic mysqli tutorial"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to read up more on [MySQL Improved Extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Here are a few pointers to get you going:

1. You are mixing procedural MySQLi (`mysqli_connect()`) and OO-style MySQLi (`$db->query()`). Try to connect with: `$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`
2. You forgot to set the value of `$id` which is used on line 3: `$sql_title = "SELECT title FROM posts WHERE post_id='$id'";`
3. This is probably a mistake on your part: `<link href="./includes/db_connect.php">`

Looking further into your code, we might encounter problems here:

```
$query_title = $db->query($sql_title); 
$row = $query_title->fetch_object();
$postTitle = $query_title;
```

Notice that `$query_title` contains the query to database, which returns an mysqli result. And you are trying to assign that to the variable called `$postTitle`, which you later `echo`ed below.

Try to change the above to this:

```
$query_title = $db->query($sql_title); 
$row = $query_title->fetch_object();
$postTitle = $row->title;
```

To make life simpler, you could actually use `fetch_assoc()`, which should be good enough for your use. If you can, read more about [MySQLi manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and take a look at the examples.

Comment: mixing procedural and OO is not a problem. $query_title contains no query to database. SQL injection kept in place. But yeah, an almost sensible answer at last.

Comment: Those were meant to be pointers to get the OP started on trying to fix what was wrong. I know it's not perfect, just barely sensible. But we should have the OP start somewhere basic before going to more advanced things like SQL injection prevention. At least he upgraded from mysql to mysqli extension, so that's not too bad. :)